# fabric add $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) not work

Tags: ios, xcode, google-fabric

I'm using latest Xcode 10.1.

I followed the instructions on Xcode 10 to add $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) into input files:
[image]

but when I tried to use fastlane to build it, I still get

```
❌  error: Fabric: Info.plist Error


** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/xuanliu/appannie/development/brandapp/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BrandedApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/BrandedApp.build/Release-iphoneos/BrandedApp.build/Script-7477C8581AA993830001D3B0.sh
(1 failure)
[12:16:25]: Exit status: 65
```

I checked my build setting, the info plist file shows:
[image]

What's wrong with my project setting, can somebody help?

Comment: have you solved problem?

Answer (score 2):

Solution to complete the setup of Crashlytics and/or Fabric using following:

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Search "Debug Information Format"
3. Change value of **"Debug"** from **"DWARF"** to **"DWARF with dSYM File"**
4. Build your project again.

Change "DWARF"

[image]

To "DWARF with dSYM File"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, if your info.plist is in your root directory like this:

[image]

you should change **$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/info.plist** like this:

[image]